# Maple: How having f(z) create f'(z), where z is complex variable?

Tags: maple

So I have `f(z)`, `z:= a + I*b` I want to create f`(z) capable of working with my z.

First time I tried `fd:= diff(f(z), z)` but my code fails with Error, (in `fd`) invalid input: diff received `a+I*b`, which is not valid for its 2nd argument.

So only solution I found is to create f' in 2 steps. Calculate `diff(f(z), z)` into some variable and copy output by hand into `fd:= z-> ...copied stuff...`

So what would be correct solution for such problem - how to get rid of manual copying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand what you want, but here's my suggestion for what I think you want:

1. Define f(z):

   `f := z -> whatever f does with z;`
2. Define the derivative df(z):

   `df := D(f);`

Now, if `f := z -> z^2`, then `df(a + b*I)` will evaluate to `2*a + 2*b*I`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: nope - same error =( `j := unapply(diff(f(z), z))` gives me `Error, invalid input: diff received a+I*b, which is not valid for its 2nd argument
` z is predefined as `z:= a + I * b`

Comment: Try `D` instead of `diff` (I changed the answer some minutes ago). This works for me, even if `z` is already assigned.